# What do we do about spam questions that could be marginally useful?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The recent question [Benefits of Patio Pavers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/benefits-of-patio-pavers) has had similar versions posted by the same two users, both with the same link:

- [https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/interior-design-closed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/benefits-of-patio-pavers)
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/to-level-the-paver-walkway-closed

They're not descriptively written, poorly tagged, and obviously spam. Are they an automatic close, or should we allow one to remain open (with spam link removed) to address a valid question? Or can we just ban the two (assumed) fake user accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I'm definitely not seeing any value in those questions at all.

We do have a policy on self promotion in the `/faq` ...

https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion

> #### May I promote products I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free vote-based advertising for open source projects.

... but this is just plain old spam. Good catch!